# Двойное "\" в Python

Tags: python

```
Tag = "\{}\Tag.txt"
List = ["1", "2"]            
for i in List:
    Tag = Tag.format(i)
```

, но когда прошу вывести Tag, то:

```
'\\1\\Tag.txt'
```

А должно быть:

```
'\1\Tag.txt'
```

В результате это должен быть путь к файлу. Двойной не воспринимается.
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить

Comment: Вывести как куда? В данном выводе вывелся строковый литерал, и в строковом литерале \ ОБЯЗАН быть двойным, так что всё здесь правильно

Comment: В результате это должен быть путь к файлу. Двойной не воспринимается

Comment: Это вполне корректный путь в Windows, он должен отлично восприниматься (если папка `1` на текущем диске существует, разумеется)

Comment: Мне пишет, что путь неверный(папка 1 и 2 создана)

Comment: Ну так может он и в самом деле неверный? Я только что перепроверил — если путь существует, то всё отлично работает, вот сами полюбуйтесь: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIq2K.png

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\1\\Tag.txt'

Comment: Ну значит его у вас действительно нет, больше сказать тут нечего.

Comment: Все решилось! Надо было просто убрать первые слэши

Comment: Значит файла действительно не было, о чём я и говорил 24 минуты назад.

Answer (score 2):

Символ обратного слэша `\` используется для экранированных последовательностей, также называемых escape-последовательностями. Они используются во многих языках программирования (и не только, например в формате данных JSON) и позволяют легко прописывать не совсем типичные символы, например:

- `\n` – символ переноса строки
- `\t` – символ таба ("длинного пробела")
- `\x...` – 16-ричное значение
- `\u...` – 16-битовый символ Юникода
- `\U...` – 32-битовый символ Юникода

и тому подобные. Сам символ обратный слэш обычно записывается как `\\`, что Вы и получили на выводе. В исходной строке по-хорошему его тоже надо было так прописать, и будь там не `...\Tag` а `...\tag`, то пара символов `\t` считалась бы одним символом таба, а не двумя символами слэша и маленькой Т. Просто парсер не нашёл соответствующей escape-последовательности попавшимся `\{`, `\T` и оставил их как отдельные символы.

Вообще, в Питоне чтобы увидеть строку (или другое значение) с точки зрения программиста используется функция `repr`, которая показывает значение таким, чтобы его можно было скопировать в код и получить это значение:

```
# одну и ту же строку можно записать как с escape-символами:
s = '\tHello,\nWorld!'
# так и без них  ## к сожалению сайт заменяет таб в начале на пробел
s = """ Hello,
World!"""

print(repr(s))
print(s)
```

Получаем:

```
'\tHello,\nWorld!'
    Hello,
World!
```

Вы, видимо, запускали код в консоли Питона, которая по умолчанию вызывает `repr`.